# React native How to execute function every time when i open page

Tags: react-native

I need to send request every time when i open page. Currently when i access page first time after load the app everything is ok, but if i go to another page and back after that request is not send it again.

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: i will be more specific: i have 2 pages TypesSettings and CategoriesSettings when i go to CategoriesSettings for the first time everything is ok (for example i want to execute Alert) but after that i go to TypesSettings . The problem is after i want to back from TypesSettings to CategoriesSetting the Alert not started

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go, example for a class based and functional based component to run something on every load of the screen.

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import {View} from 'react-native'

//Functional Component
const App = ()  => 
{

  useEffect(() =>
  {
     myAction();
  }, [])



  return (
    <View>

    </View>
  );
}

//Class based Component
 class App extends Component
 {

  componentDidMount()
  {
    this.myAction();
  }

  render()
  {
    return(
      <View>
        
      </View>
    )
  }

 }
```

Comment: It will be called only once on every load of the screen. If you revisit the screen, it will be called again.

Comment: If you are using `navigation.navigate()` to get to that screen, then the useEffect that you wrote will only be run the first time the the user enters the screen. However, if you use `navigation.push()` to get to the screen, then the useEffect function you wrote will indeed be executed again.
---

I came to this StackOverflow post in search of the `navigation.addListener('focus', () => {})` answer that has more upvotes.

Comment: There is a simple ```useFocusEffect()``` which does the trick rather than writing the listeners.

Comment: NICE! It looks like `useFocusEffect()` is from the `@react-navigation/native` library, which is okay if you have that installed or want to install it. Thanks for sharing that one —> I did not know about it as an option.  Thankfully, I already have that library installed, so I can use your suggestion.

Answer (score 12):

You have to add focus listener so when you go back, It will refresh the data like

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';

function AppScreen({ navigation }) {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
      // The screen is focused
      // Call any action and update data
    });

    // Return the function to unsubscribe from the event so it gets removed on unmount
    return unsubscribe;
  }, [navigation]);

  return <View />;
}
```

source : https://reactnavigation.org/docs/function-after-focusing-screen/